# NPM not working (Cannot find module 'internal/fs' - nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

NPM error on update. I recently update to Node version 7.x. Now npm is not working.

I am unable to locate the error, it may be due to - 
`npm ERR! Cannot find module 'internal/fs'`. 
 
 I get the following when I run `sudo npm update -g` -

```
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-101-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "update" "-g"
npm ERR! node v7.1.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND

npm ERR! Cannot find module 'internal/fs'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

My `/etc/profile.d/nodejs.sh` has the following contents:

```
NODE_PATH=/usr/lib/nodejs:/usr/lib/node_modules:/usr/share/javascript
export NODE_PATH
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to remove the npm directory (typically /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm) and then reinstall one of the official node tarballs, which includes npm (you can find the latest from http://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/).

Did you upgrade from an older version of node?

If so, that is probably part of the reason why you are having this issue. Older versions of `graceful-fs` (a dependency of npm) did things that are no longer available in node v7.

Comment: Reinstallation worked, commands run in order - `sudo apt-get remove nodejs` ;`sudo apt-get remove npm`; `sudo apt-get install nodejs`

Answer (score 1):

According to this [thread](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/14438), updating `npm` to version 4 will solve your problem, try:

```
npm i -g npm@4
```

If this doesn't work, try:

```
~/.n/n/versions/node/7.0.0/bin/npm i -g npm@4
```

Comment: Along those lines I was not able to do that until I downgraded using `n` to 6.x.x, ran `npm i -g npm@4`, then upgraded back to 7.x.x.

Comment: For Mac OS X and Homebrew: [1] Find out which versions of node have been installed with `brew info node` [2] Switch the node version back to the one before 7, eg: `brew switch node 6.2.0` [3]  Update npm as matheusr suggests - `npm i -g npm@4` [4] Switch back to the latest version of node - `brew switch node 7.2.1`

Answer (score 0):

delete node_modules directory and then type in your console "npm install". For a reason that I dont know, if you only update npm, it does not fix the error, but re-installing npm everything is gonna be allright.

Comment: i know this is old, but when you say `delete node_modules directory` do you mean that folder in a project, or your main one on your system? I'm on OSX 10.10.5

Comment: If you are using a framework, delete from your project, and then reinstall from your framework's console.

Answer (score 0):

For me, if I facing error "cannot find module internal/fs", it would be refer to command path. Better find the command path:

```
npm config get prefix
```

put into system environment path.
It is worked for me after facing the error several days.