# Getting Error when trying to install browser-sync ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, browser-sync

1. Node is Updated to latest stable version v7.4.0

   This is the error message I get when trying to install browser-sync:

   ```
   sudo npm install -g browser-sync
   ```

> 'npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-59-generic npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node"
>   "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "browser-sync" npm ERR! node
>   v7.4.0 npm ERR! npm  v4.0.5 npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
>
> npm ERR! Cannot find module 'internal/fs' npm ERR!  npm ERR! If you
>   need help, you may report this error at: npm ERR!
>   https://github.com/npm/npm/issues
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     /home/pedro/npm-debug.log '

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NPM not working (Cannot find module 'internal/fs' - nodejs)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40663489/npm-not-working-cannot-find-module-internal-fs-nodejs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Solved the issue:

NPM Module was not supported by node v7:

So I downgraded to node v6.4.0 and it allowed me install browser-sync with no problems!

```
    sudo npm cache clean -f
    sudo npm install -g n
    sudo n 6.9.5
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs when you are installing a old module(as written in your package.json) but it is not available on git due to update in their version.

for solving this issue.

```
    1.Need to install the project’s local dependencies (that’s where it’s looking for browser-sync). To do that,
    2.cd into the project directory and run npm install.
    3.You can also try npm i browser-sync --save
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to upgrade `npm` also (currently `npm@next` – `npm -g install npm@next` if you have it installed globally.