# ng serve fails on Angular 2 created with angular CLI on BoUoW

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am running BoUoW in elevation mode and have installed @angular/cli and created a sample project using the new command.

When i try to run the app by npm start it fails by stating the error ng serve failed, and blames it on npm and node version issues or the app itself. npm and node version are the latest ones.

Any angular 2 expert advice or am i using the wrong boilerplate app?

Edit:

1. @angular/cli: 1.0.0-beta.32.3
2. node: 6.9.5
3. npm: 3.10.10

Edit 2: (error logs)

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@4.1.2
3 info using node@v7.5.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle testapp@0.0.0~prestart: testapp@0.0.0
6 silly lifecycle testapp@0.0.0~prestart: no script for prestart, continuing
7 info lifecycle testapp@0.0.0~start: testapp@0.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle testapp@0.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle testapp@0.0.0~start: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/mnt/c/Users/sande/Desktop/testapp/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
10 verbose lifecycle testapp@0.0.0~start: CWD: /mnt/c/Users/sande/Desktop/testapp
11 silly lifecycle testapp@0.0.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'ng serve' ]
12 silly lifecycle testapp@0.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle testapp@0.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
14 verbose stack Error: testapp@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:279:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:192:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:192:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:890:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
15 verbose pkgid testapp@0.0.0
16 verbose cwd /mnt/c/Users/sande/Desktop/testapp
17 error Linux 3.4.0+
18 error argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
19 error node v7.5.0
20 error npm  v4.1.2
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error testapp@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the testapp@0.0.0 start script 'ng serve'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the testapp package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     ng serve
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs testapp
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls testapp
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Edit 3: Steps to reproduce

Note i am using BoUoW on 14393.693 / 14.04.5 LTS

```
sudo n v7.5.0
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng new my-project
cd my-project
npm start
```

Comment: can you share the error log?

Comment: added the error log as requested. I get the same error for the combination of npm 6.5.0

Comment: the concern is that its about only  5 lines of bash script thats messing it up. I am not really doing anything special here.

Comment: Can you also share your package.json?

Answer (score 0):

You've older version of node and npm. Current versions are:

node - v7.5.0
nam - 4.1.2

Please upgrade and try it again. 
By the way, with Angular CLI, you can just ng serve. No need to use 
npm start.

Comment: this doesnt work for me, after i upgraded to 7.5.0 ng new gives an error "npm ERR! Cannot find module 'internal/fs'"

Comment: Did you upgrade both node and npm? Were they successful? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40663489/npm-not-working-cannot-find-module-internal-fs-nodejs.
If they are successful, then in your project directory delete node_modules
rm -rf node_modules <br>
npm install<br>
ng serve

Comment: yep it nodejs and npm installed successfully, but when i try to install dependencies via npm install on 7.5.0 / 4.x it results in an error Cannot find module 'internal/fs'

also i am using n to switch between versions. of node and npm